# UI Slider acts differently in Play mode and a standalone build (Unity Engine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, slider

I have a UI slider. When holding down the left mouse button, its value decreases. I use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` in order to make this work. The code works fine. However, when I test the slider in Play mode (embedded in Unity) its value decreases **a lot faster** than in windowed Play mode (2 sec vs 5 sec). On a Windows standalone build, it gets even slower (15 sec). I recently checked it on macOS and the problem is the same. UI Slider timing is extremely important in my game mechanics.

I may assume it depends on the framerate, but both Play mode and a standalone build have 150-200 FPS.

[GIF that clearly demonstrates the timing difference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOQlZ.gif)

Player.cs

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxFuel = 1000;
    public int fuelAmount;

    public FuelBar fuelBar;

    void Start()
    {
        fuelAmount = maxFuel;
        fuelBar.SetMaxFuel(maxFuel);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            SpendFuel(1);
        }
    }

    void SpendFuel(int fuel)
    {
        fuelAmount -= fuel;
        fuelBar.SetFuel(fuelAmount);
    }
}
```

FuelBar.cs

```
public class FuelBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider fuelBar;

    public void SetMaxFuel(int fuel)
    {
        fuelBar.maxValue = fuel;
        fuelBar.value = fuel;
    }

    public void SetFuel(int fuel)
    {
        fuelBar.value = fuel;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change fuel to float and multiply it in update by `Time.deltaTime`.

```
SpendFuel(1f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Might also want to change `1f` to something larger as that is now x per second.